# Customize SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have requirement where in I am creating a table dynamically(number of columns may change based on input parameter to my procedure through which I am creating this table) with data in the table like below.

```
PK col1 col2 col3
A  null 1-2  3-4
B  null null  4-5
C  null 5-6  null
```

Now the requirement is I want to extract only the columns where at least there should be 1 record without null and spool the whole data into a file. My output should be like below (col1 exlluded from output as it has all nulls).

```
PK col2 col3 
A  1-2  3-4
B  null  4-5
C  5-6  null
```

Can anybody provide any hints to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know any way using plain SQL. Did you try PL/SQL as well?

Comment: Don't know enough about dynamic sql but you should be able to get a list of the relevant columns from the dba_tab_cols dictionary (or all_tab_cols if you don't have access) by running select column_name from dba_tab_cols where num_nulls <> 0 and table_name = 'xyz' (this assumes the table's statistics are up to date)

Comment: @BrianDeMilia - I won't get the desired output if I use above query as I need to exclude columns with all nulls. But I can get the total number of records in the table and compare it with num_nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used num_nulls from all_tab_cols and achieved result as per my requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be very efficient I suspect, but you can use COUNT() to determine if there are any only NULLS in a column because COUNT(column_here) will only add 1 for each non-null value. Hence if the count is zero that column is only NULLs.

This can then be combined into a query to generate a valid select statement and then that executed immediate (being careful of course to avoid sql injection).

Anyway, here's an example:

```
select
     'select '
   || substr((
        select
                 case when count(COL1) > 0 then ',col1' else '' end
              || case when count(COL2) > 0 then ',col2' else '' end
              || case when count(COL3) > 0 then ',col3' else '' end
        from a_table
       ),2,8000)
   || ' from '
   || ' a_table'
   as sql_string
from dual
;
```

see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1669a/2)

result by the above is:

```
|                     SQL_STRING |
|--------------------------------|
| select col2,col3 from  a_table |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try. First, create a function to generate your query, returning a REF CURSOR:

```
create or replace function select_non_nulls() return sys_refcursor as
  myQuery varchar2(500);
  myCur   sys_refcursor;
begin

  select 'select ' || listagg(col, ', ') within group (order by col) || ' from test'
  into myQuery
  from
  (
    select case when max(col1) is null then null else 'col1' end col from test
    union all
    select case when max(col2) is null then null else 'col2' end col from test
    union all
    select case when max(col3) is null then null else 'col3' end col from test
  )
  ;

  open myCur for myQuery;

  return myCur;

end;
/
```

Then use it in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> exec :rc := select_non_nulls;
SQL> print rc;
```